# Highcharts, MySql and Vaadin

Tags: java, jquery, highcharts, vaadin

I am looking for an example on using Highcharts with data from MYSQL in java with Vaadin framework. I literally don't know whether it is possible.When i tried for Vaadin InvientCharts I was redirected to Highcharts. Highcharts looks promising for my project but i want to use along with Java and Mysql. Please elaborate me if I am wrong. I am beginner to this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Invient Charts (which is Java wrapper for JavaScript-based HighCharts) is totally independent on the data source. The Invient Charts package contains instructions and an example how to use it in your Vaadin project.

You can use [Vaadin SQLContainer addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-sqlcontainer) to get the data from your database. There's a simple example behind that link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPAContainer or HbnContainer.

Answer (score 0):

The addon suggested my @miq seems to be not maintained anymore.

This one looks more current:
https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/highchartsapi-add-on